# Conditional formatting not evaluated in JSONSchema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm trying to validate firewall rules denoted in JSON.

Given a minimal example of my JSONSchema as follows:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "Example",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "from": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/addressGroup"
    },
    "action": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["binat", "pass"]
    }
  },
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "action": {
            "const": "binat"
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "from": {
            "format": "ip-address"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": [
    "from",
    "action"
  ],
  "definitions": {
    "addressGroup": {
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "^[ !<a-zA-Z].+$"
    }
  }
}
```

The following JSON passes validation:

```
{
    "action": "pass",
    "from": "test"
}
```

But for this JSON, the "from" field is evaluated against `addressGroup` rather than against the `"format": "ip-address"`.

```
{
    "action": "binat",
    "from": "10.1.1.1"
}
```

I'd expect the "then" clause to be triggered and force the formatting of the "from" field in accordance with the "ip-address" definition.

A minimal demo can be found here: https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/EsQVoaXw

What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For draft-07, the designated format for IP Addresses is `ipv4` or `ipv6`

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-7.3.4

Additionally, `format` by default does nothing, and it must be enabled.

This has been further clarified in draft 2019-09 and formalised for predictable behaviour in draft 2020-12.

You may have to enable it within your implementation. I'm not sure what jsonschemavalidator.net does as it's not open source. jsonschema.dev does not have `format` based validation enabled.

You have correctly used `if/then`, but `addressGroup` in your schema will still be applied (It's not clear if this was your intent or not).

Updating based on your comment:

To only apply `addressGroup` when the `if` schema fails, you need to use the `else` keyword (if / then / else logic), moving `properties.form` there.

```
{
  "if": false,
  "then": {},
  "else": {
    "properties": {
      "from": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/addressGroup"
      }
    }
  }
...
}
```

Comment: I see. I'll check some other implementations as well. How would I ensure that addressGroup wouldn't be applied? Ideally I'd only want it to apply when the `action != 'binat'`